# How to implement multi selection recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement a RecyclerView that supports Multi Selection in items, I have seen other questions about this subject, but the main difference is that I need to be able to select outside of the Adapter.
For example, let's say I have a Dialog called SelectionDialog, this dialog displays some Selection options, such as "Select All", so if I click it, I should be able to select all my recyclerview's items, and this items should change something to let the user know which ones are selected, in my case, I decided to (using MaterialCardView) add a little color border to the item to distinguish if its selected or if it is not.
I can select all the tasks with a public method in the adapter (change their isSelected boolean property to true), however, I can't figure out how to add that border to the respective item's ViewHolder, mostly because I can´t have access to it.
Here's my code:

```
//SelectDialog    
AllB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listadapter.SelectAll();
                Touched = true;
                dismiss();
            }
        });

//ListAdapter    
public void SelectAll()    
    {    
        for(int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++)    
            ListItem item = mList.get(i);   
            item.setSelected(true);
            //I should be able to add the border to the item here     
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `notifyDataSetChanged();`
//ListAdapter

```
public void SelectAll()    
    {    
        for(int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++)    {
            ListItem item = mList.get(i);   
            item.setSelected(true);
            //I should be able to add the border to the item here     
        }   
notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

in your onBindViewHolder 
...

```
 if(item.IsSelected()){
    //Change the View border here
    }else{
    //Default View Background
    }
```

Comment: Sometimes "OnBindViewHolder" is not getting called

Comment: You should find that in which scenario you missed it